# Flash Builder folder structure + .fla workflow

Tags: actionscript-3, workflow, flexbuilder

I built 3 variations of a game for different platforms (i.e. Facebook, mobile etc.) in Flash CS4.

I now have the following structure (5 folders):

Facebook
Mobile
Website
Shared_classes
Shared_assets

In each of the top three folders there is a .fla file.
Every .fla uses assets and classes from the "shared folders" but also platform-unique code.

*I would now like to migrate this project to Flash Builder but*
1) what is the best approach to stay organized?
2) what is the best .fla file workflow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, that depends... if you ever want to migrate to Flex4 and use Maven2 to automate the build, you might want to organize your project as follows:

```
project-folder
|- common
|  |- CommonModule.fla
|  |- src
|  |- test
|- platform1
|  |- Platform1Module.fla
|  |- src
|  |- test
|- platform2
|  |- Platform2Module.fla
|  |- src
|  |- test
|- ...
```

I unfortunately didn't organize it this way, and have [recently been clobbered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1482793/complex-maven2-with-flex4-setup) when trying to switch away from Adobe's over-priced IDE that doesn't even support building from the commandline. (How on earth is one supposed to perform integration testing or define pre-/post-commit hooks without commandline builds?)